# How to prove that if $\sum a_{n}^2$ converges, $\sum |a_{n}|$ also converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can prove the converse, but not this one. Actually, it's a prove or disprove question. Any hints?

Comment: This is obviously false. A counterexample is $a_n=1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is false ! Here is a well-known counterexample: $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. $\sum_n a_n$ diverges and $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges.